# Download failed. There are no HTTP transports available which can complete the requested request

Tags: wordpress, wamp, wampserver

When I try to install theme on wamp server it shows a line as below 
Download failed. There are no HTTP transports available which can complete the requested request. 
How to fix it?

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 19):

I think you probably need to activate the php_curl extension to solve this issue.

Do this to activate the php_curl extension :-

Left click wampmanager ( thats the W icon in the system tray )

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions
```

If the php_curl extension is not `ticked` then click it and it will activate the extension and restart Apache for you.

It may also be necessary to activate `php_openssl` in the same way, depending on the theme's requirements.

Comment: Thanks. this pretty much fixed the issue :)

Comment: If this still doesn't fix your problem, also uncomment the open ssl extension:

extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: What I did is to enable `allow url include` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that:

1. allow_url_fopen = On
2. Under your PHP Extensions allow php_curl

Restart your Server.

WordPress will try to use several transports to make the request. First it will try curl, then streams, then fsock.

If your server is set up with curl and your version of curl supports SSL (required for using the API), then it will use that.

Next it will try to use streams (fopen). If fopen is set up and working on your server, it is set to applow opening from a URL (allow_url_fopen), and openssl is set up and functional, then it will send the request with streams.

Lastly, if your server has fsockopen set up and usable, and openssl is also set up and functional, then it will use fsockopen to make the request.

If none of those work, then it will be unable to send any. This is all built into the WordPress HTTP API.

If your server can't make the requests, it will be unable to make many other requests as well.

You need to get your host to set up a transport method that WordPress can use.

Comment: Enable php_curl is exactly how I fixed it on Uniform Server WAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you face similar kind of error after trying to update any plugin or wordpress itself from localhost using your Xampp, then don’t worry. You could avoid this error and update it from your localhost enabling PHP curl extension.

To enable it:
1. Open your “php.ini” file.
2. Find the line which says “;extension=php_curl.dll”.
3. Now simply remove “; or semi-colon” from the line.
4. That’s it. Restart your Xampp and now it should work updating without error.

Comment: This is brilliant, it fixes the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to activate the php_curl extension to solve this issue as well

as uncommented the extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini file.

Do this to uncomment the following extension:-

## wampicon -> php -> php.ini

then search the following extension in php.ini file.

Hope this will help you to resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Setting both of these extensions in the php.ini file worked for me:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin


extension=php_openssl.dll 
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable php_curl.dll from your php.ini file, this should correct the error. Just remove the ; on the line stated to correct the error.

Hope this help.

Cheers!